# Flutter create game board

Tags: flutter

I've created a game in Python that I'm trying to recreate in Flutter. It has a grid layout board 4 x 3 like this image:

[image]

I'm thinking that I want to use Material with child Ink.image to display the board pieces.

My code:

```
/*- Main method --------------------------------------------------- */
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Cat Attack"),
        ),
        body: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(
              child: new GridView.builder(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 4, // 4 columns of board buttons
                    childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 9.0,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 9.0),
                itemCount: buttonsList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) => new SizedBox(
                  width: 100.0,
                  height: 100.0,

                  child: new Material(
                    elevation: 4.0,
                    shape: CircleBorder(),
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    child: new Ink.image(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/animals/cat_blue_128.png'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      width: 64.0,
                      height: 64.0,
                    ),
                  ),

                ),
              ),
            ),

            new RaisedButton(
              child: new Text(
                "Reset",
                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
              color: Colors.red,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              onPressed: resetGame,
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
```

However I get a lot of error messages:

```
Performing hot reload... Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86... I/flutter ( 5390): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ I/flutter ( 5390): The following assertion was thrown building LayoutBuilder: I/flutter ( 5390): A build function returned null. I/flutter ( 5390): The offending widget is: LayoutBuilder I/flutter ( 5390): Build functions must never return null. To return an empty space that causes the building widget to I/flutter ( 5390): fill available room, return "new Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as I/flutter ( 5390): possible, return "new Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)". I/flutter ( 5390):  I/flutter ( 5390): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: I/flutter ( 5390): #0      debugWidgetBuilderValue.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:270:7) I/flutter ( 5390): #1   debugWidgetBuilderValue (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:287:4) I/flutter ( 5390): #2      _LayoutBuilderElement._layout.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart:112:11) I/flutter ( 5390): #3      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2257:19) I/flutter ( 5390): #4      _LayoutBuilderElement._layout (package:flutter/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart:107:11) I/flutter ( 5390): #5      RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1728:58) I/flutter ( 5390):
#6      PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:797:15) I/flutter ( 5390):
#7      RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1728:13) I/flutter ( 5390):
#8      _RenderLayoutBuilder.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart:205:5) I/flutter ( 5390): #9      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#10     RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:259:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #11     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#12     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #13     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#14     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #15     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#16     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #17     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1206:11) I/flutter ( 5390): #18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#19     RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:259:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #20     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#21     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#23     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #24     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#25     RenderSliverGrid.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_grid.dart:571:18) I/flutter ( 5390): #26     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#27     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:182:11) I/flutter ( 5390): #28     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#29     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:407:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #30     RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1322:12) I/flutter ( 5390): #31     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1240:20) I/flutter ( 5390): #32     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#33     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #34     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#35     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #36     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#37     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #38     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#39     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #40     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#41     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #42     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#43     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #44     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#45     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #46     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#47     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #48     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#49     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:798:17) I/flutter ( 5390):
#50     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#51     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:142:11) I/flutter ( 5390): #52     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:431:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#53     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:212:7) I/flutter ( 5390): #54     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:356:14) I/flutter ( 5390): #55     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#56     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #57     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#58     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #59     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1206:11) I/flutter ( 5390): #60     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#61     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #62     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#63     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #64     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#65     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #66     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#67     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #68     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#69     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #70     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#71     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #72     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#73     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #74     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#75     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #76     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3032:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #77     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#78     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:510:15) I/flutter ( 5390):
#79     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#80     __RenderTheatre&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #81     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#82     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #83     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#84     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #85     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#86     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #87     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#88     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #89     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#90     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13) I/flutter ( 5390): #91     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#92     RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:151:13) I/flutter ( 5390):
#93     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1507:7) I/flutter ( 5390):
#94     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:766:18) I/flutter ( 5390):
#95     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:336:19) I/flutter ( 5390):
#96     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:701:13) I/flutter ( 5390):
#97     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:275:5) I/flutter ( 5390):
#98     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:990:15) I/flutter ( 5390):
#99     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:930:9) I/flutter ( 5390):
#100    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:751:7) I/flutter ( 5390): #102    _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate/runtime/lib/timer_impl.dart:382:19) I/flutter ( 5390):
#103    _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/lib/timer_impl.dart:416:5) I/flutter ( 5390):
#104    _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/lib/isolate_patch.dart:171:12) I/flutter ( 5390): (elided one frame from package dart:async) I/flutter ( 5390): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ I/flutter ( 5390): Another exception was thrown: A build function returned null. I/chatty  ( 5390): uid=10089(one.askit.cat_attack) Thread-2 identical 4 lines I/flutter ( 5390): Another exception was thrown: A build function returned null. Reloaded 2 of 438 libraries in 1 627ms. I/flutter ( 5390): Another exception was thrown: A build function returned null. I/chatty  ( 5390): uid=10089(one.askit.cat_attack) Thread-2 identical 3 lines I/flutter ( 5390): Another exception was thrown: A build function returned null. I/flutter ( 5390): Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: assets/animals/cat_blue_128.png
```

I have the animal image so Im not sure why I get the error.

[image]

Comment: Did you put these images name in `pubspec.yaml` file?

Comment: CopsOnRoad: Aha, so I will try to put them in that file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the resource you want to use in the pubspec.yaml file.

From docs -

> Flutter uses the pubspec.yaml file, located at the root of your project, to identify assets required by an app.

Add it like this -

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - animals/cat_blue_128.png
```

Also, you can remove the `new` keyword for instance creation as it is not required with Dart 2.